# Changing global variable in main process within a spawned process using multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

My sample code is as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
GLOBAL_VAR = 0

def try_change_global_var(notused):
    global GLOBAL_VAR
    print(f"My own GLOBAL_VAR in current process starts as: {GLOBAL_VAR}")
    GLOBAL_VAR = 1
    print("I tried to change GLOBAL_VAR to 1")
    return "change"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Pool(4)
    result = p1.map(try_change_global_var, range(4))
    print(result)
    print(f"GLOBAL_VAR in main process is still: {GLOBAL_VAR}")
    p1.close()
```

I read that every spawned Python process gets its own global variable, but if you take a look at my console output, it seems as if all 4 spawned processes were accessing the same variable, because it was immediately changed from 0 to 1 and it stayed 1. When the 4 processes finished the global variable from main was of course still 0.

```
My own GLOBAL_VAR in current process starts as: 0
I tried to change GLOBAL_VAR to 1
My own GLOBAL_VAR in current process starts as: 1
I tried to change GLOBAL_VAR to 1
My own GLOBAL_VAR in current process starts as: 1
I tried to change GLOBAL_VAR to 1
My own GLOBAL_VAR in current process starts as: 1
I tried to change GLOBAL_VAR to 1
['change', 'change', 'change', 'change']
GLOBAL_VAR in main process is still: 0
```

I could change it within main, based on the list of returns from the called function, but that is not what I want. I want to share memory and change the global variable in the main process, from the spawned processes.

I was unable to get a working toy example with `multiprocessing.Value` and would appreciate some help. The examples I found were not using Pool and were able to pass multiple arguments to the functions they were running in parallel processes.

OS: Windows 10
Python 3.9.5

Comment: What is your OS and Python version? There was a behavior change in how this stuff is handled between 3.7 and 3.8.

Comment: I am using OS: Windows 10 and Python 3.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working exactly as intended.  When you spawn a process, you are making a copy of your current environment, and giving it to the new process.  Changes made by that process happen in that process, and only in that process.

So every process changes **its own** `GLOBAL_VAR` to 1, but that value is completely independent of the `GLOBAL_VAR` in the main process.  Python provides "shared variables" if you need to use a variable across multiple threads, but they are somewhat expensive. ([`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects))

Comment: If changes made by a process only happen in that process, how do some of the processes print that ```GLOBAL_VAR``` is 1 before they set it to 1? The question does reference that point - "it seems as if all 4 spawned processes were accessing the same variable".

Comment: Try adding `print(current_process())` to your worker code, where `current_process` is imported from `multiprocessing`.  I suspect that more than one of your "jobs" are running on the same thread since the jobs are so small.

Comment: Yes, the answer in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458097/changing-global-variable-in-main-process-within-a-spawned-process-using-multipro?noredirect=1#comment122769342_69458474) is the real answer (except there are no "threads" involved here).  If you put a `time.sleep(1)` in as the first line of `try_change_global_var` then they will get scheduled in different workers from the pool. You might look into using the [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) submodule.

Comment: @wim.  You're right.  I meant to type "process" instead of "thread".  I'd correct it, but stackoverflow isn't letting me.

Comment: @FrankYellin: my slip on "threads" not yours.

Comment: I added 1 second sleep time and am getting back now the expected global value, 0 for each process. Thanks for the tip in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902418/12102460 I guess this was some sort of optimization and I didn't actually have 4 processes, but only 1 that got reused for the last 3 function calls.

Comment: You probably created four processes, but they didn't all start "working" at the same time.  One of the processes grabbed a job, finished it, and asked for another job before one of the other processes finished setting up. Welcome to the fun world of multiprocessor programming.  A lot of assumptions go out the window.